# Summernote js editor

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, summernote

How do I make the font name display when I'm setting up my own options for SummerNote v0.8.2?

Here's my **setup code**, running on document ready:

```
$('.summernote').summernote(
            {
                height: 100
                , width: 350
                , placeholder: 'Please enter your contact information here'
                , dialogsFade: true                                        
                , fontNames: ['Arial', 'Calibri', 'Consolas', 'Courier New', 'Garamond', 'Georgia', 'Lucida Console', 'Lucida Sans', 'Segoe UI', 'Tahoma',
                    'Tempus Sans ITC', 'Times New Roman', 'Trebuchet MS', 'Verdana']
                , toolbar: [                        
                     ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']]
                    ,['fontname', ['fontname']], 
                    , ['fontsize', ['fontsize']]                        
                    , ['color', ['color']]                        
                ]
            }
            );
```

And **here is how it displays with the above setup**, (mouse hovering over, causing Font Family to be visible):

[image]

I would like it to display the font name too, and not just within the dropdown list.  When I use the default setup, with no options, I can see it - like this, also shown on their website:

[image]

Setting a default font doesn't fix this either.  Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried this? fontNamesIgnoreCheck: ['Arial','Calbiri','etc']

Comment: Thank you.  That being said, now that a font name is showing up (only Helvetica is visible, though I don't have this on my list.  Also, when I select something the dropdown doesn't change, always displays helvetica.  I noticed this on their website too.  Using Chrome 53.0.2785.89 m (current version, updated today).  Thoughts?

Comment: Hmmm. Let me go try it later. Will give you feedback.

Comment: The drop-down only stays changed when you've selected text then changed it via the drop down.

Answer (score 1):

Have basic set up like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $('.summernote').summernote({
                    height: 500,
                    toolbar: [
                ['style', ['style']],
                ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']]
                ],
```

Font area looks like this:

[image]

Note the line:

```
['fontname', ['fontname']],
```

Not sure what happened so edited and gave link that helped me some:

https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/651